# Cadillac CTS "Traction Control Off" displayed after driving 15 mins

Tags: electronic-control-module, gm, cadillac, bcm, cts

After driving 15 mins the "Traction Control Off" light is displayed on dashboard and radio displays "Service Brake Assist".

All go away after engine is turned off for about 20 mins.

It recently got new Electronic Control Module and Body Control Module.

I barely understand that something is sending too much power to some electronic component but what?

Comment: You really need to get the ABS/TC code(s) read. This will give you your best indication of what's going on. I don't think it would have much to do with either of the components you have replaced, because the ABS is usually it's own system and cohabitates with the traction control (because they usually work in tandem).

Comment: There are no codes.